# Amazon Web Services with iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, web, service

Good Day,

I have been more or less coding my own PHP scripts and using mysql for server-side stuff on my own server. I am quite interested in trying Amazon Web services.

Can I know if there is a free option to use their LAMP stack? Also, is there an iOS API available where I can create a database easily and just use the API for iOS to do retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

Yep there is a [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) option available where you can try a micro EC2 instance (a few AMIs already have Ubuntu + Apache + PHP5 installed as default) and a micro RDS (MySQL or others) database.

There is also a good iOS SDK [available](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/), even though it does not support all the AWS services.

Comment: I am using the iOS SDK and would like to get items based on their date. Do you happen to know how to do it. It seems the only way to search is SimpleDBGetAttributesRequest, where I have to loop through the giant database of dates and see which one matches the attribute/date

Comment: That is another question though ;-) Anyway i think you have a chance to query your data using a select other than getattributes. Take a look at this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingSelect.html). [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonSimpleDBClient.html#//api/name/select:) you can read about the `select:` docs in the iOS SDK